# While importing Excel file to QTP i'm getting the following msg "The operation failed because the application is busy"?

Tags: qtp

This is the code,

```
dim q_app
Set q_app=createobject ("Quicktest.application")
q_app.Launch
q_app.new
q_app.Visible =true
msgbox (" opens")
call q_app.Test.DataTable.Importsheet ("C:\xlfile.xls",1,1)
q_app.Test.DataTable.export ("C:\name-runtime.xls")
msgbox("opens")
q_app.Test.SaveAs("C:\testedxlfile")
q_app.Visible=true
q_app.Quit
Set q_app = nothing
```

And i'm skipping that step, again it show's the general error in line 7.

Thanks 
Vignesh

Comment: Im a beginner to Qtp, please suggest some blogs for learning QTP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QTP's automation is supposed to be used in order to drive tests from the outside. 
When I put the code you wrote in a standalone `.vbs` file it ran properly, I did get the *application is busy* error when running it from inside QTP since it's meant to be used to construct a test which can then be run and not to modify the data table of an test which is currently being run.

If you want to modify the current test it's much simpler, just use the `DataTable` object directly from the test (no need to create the QTP object)

```
DataTable.ImportSheet "C:\xlfile.xls", 1, 1
```

Comment: Is there any other way to import a excel sheet to datatable?